# Powershell send commans to some putty windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I am looking for powershell code to send text to some putty windows (same as what putty command sender does).
I found a similar example below which send text to some notepad windows - it works.
However, I made 1 word change from notepad to putty, it does not work for putty.

How can I update the code to make it work for putty? Thank you.

Below is code for notepad (the line for putty is commented):

```
#requires -Version 2
function Out-Notepad
{
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [String]
    [AllowEmptyString()] 
    $Text
  )

  begin
  {
    $sb = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
  }

  process
  {
    $null = $sb.AppendLine($Text)
  }
  end
  {
    $text = $sb.ToString()

    $processes = Get-Process notepad
    # $processes = Get-Process putty

    $sig = '
      [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
      [DllImport("User32.dll")]public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
    '
   
    foreach ($process in $processes) {
        $null = $process.WaitForInputIdle()

        $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name APISendMessage -PassThru
        Write-Output type: $type
        $hwnd = $process.MainWindowHandle
        Write-Output hwnd: $hwnd
        [IntPtr]$child = $type::FindWindowEx($hwnd, [IntPtr]::Zero, "Edit", $null)
        Write-Output child: $child
        $null = $type::SendMessage($child, 0x000C, 0, $text)
        Write-Output "---------------------"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, literally from start to end. `WaitForInputIdle` doesn't do what you think it does. The use of `FindWindowEx` is insufficient to identify the window. And sending random messages is not how you automate an application. Use UI Automation instead. That'll at least solve one of those issues.

Comment: I found the code on internet. Tested it, it works fine for notepad. I am new to powershell. Great if you can help show some working code.

Comment: PowerShell and UI automation is a well-discussed topic all over the web (articles, blogs, tools like AutoIT, Selenium, and even the use of  `argh `SendKeys) as well as on Youtube videos. Why are you trying to send commands to Putty windows, vs just running the putty command in the script? You don't need any putty window open at all. Putty has a command-line version [`PLINK`](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter7.html), that you can fully automate using whatever language you choose.

Comment: Also, that code, I've seen before, and it does work as designed. However, why did you add those other lines?  They serve no purpose, based on the goals of the script. ANy automation has timing issues. That code going a session that is not already started, like send keys, can miss the startup altogether, just like SendKeys, regardless of the language used. Try it by sending a text string to say winword.exe or wordpad.exe. It will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.

There are many examples of automating putty command via command-line plink via PowerShell. Plink is just a putty command-line executable, and thus you'd run it via PowerShell like any other executable. As documented here:

> • ***PowerShell: Running Executables***
>
> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

A quick web search using your favorite search engine will list them for you.

> [PowerShell using Plink](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20using%20plink%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Example hit(s)

> [Powershell + Plink.exe (Putty) – Execute a command on a remote Linux Device](https://shaundunmall.wordpress.com/powershell-execute-a-command-on-a-remote-linux-device/)

```
$plinkPath = "c:\Users\public\Downloads\plink.exe"

$OSun = "root" # User name required by PLINK (Putty) to SSH to Linux Primary Server
$OSpw = "rOoTpAsSwOrD" # Password required by PLINK (Putty) to SSH to Linux Primary Server

$LinuxServer   = "myLinuxServer" # Server name, must resolve on your desktop machine
$remoteCommand = """ls"""
$localCommand  = "$plinkPath $LinuxServer -l $OSun -pw $OSpw $remoteCommand"
$result        = Invoke-Expression($localCommand)
```

[Calling Putty via Powershell using Plink - how to auto answer the security key question](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-PowerCLI-Discussions/Calling-Putty-via-Powershell-using-Plink-how-to-auto-answer-the/td-p/362314)

```
Write-Output "yes" | 
PLINK.EXE -ssh $remoteserver -P 22 -pw $password -m $command
```

[Powershell and Plink](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/powershell_remoting-24/18410/powershell-and-plink)

```
$Params = @(
    "-l $SwitchLogon"
    "-pw $SwitchPsswd"
    "-m . $SwitchCliCommand"
    "$_"
)

& C:\Scripts\Brocadeswitch\plink.exe $Params
```

Even the script you say you found is overkill for your use case. Again SendKeys has its issues, but you could do this. The delay is a requirement to allow the app to load. This is the issue. Different machines require different times.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$SendKeys = [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]

# Sending ot notepad
Start-Process -FilePath 'notepad.exe'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
$SendKeys::SendWait("~{TAB}$env:USERNAME~")

# Sending ot wordpad
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Wordpad.lnk'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
$SendKeys::SendWait("~{TAB}$env:USERNAME~")

# Sending powershell instance
Start-Process -FilePath 'powershell.exe' '-NoProfile', '-NoLogo'
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
$SendKeys::SendWait("~{TAB}Get-Date~")
```

You could do this as a delay tactic as well.

```
# Using Do/Unitl 
$MainWindowTitle = $null
Start-Process -FilePath 'notepad.exe'
do 
{
    $MainWindowTitle = (Get-Process -Name notepad).MainWindowTitle
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
}
until ($MainWindowTitle -ne '')
$SendKeys::SendWait("~{TAB}$env:USERNAME~")
```

So, I hope you are getting that use Powershell for UI automation is not really a thing to do, since, though it can, it is not its strong suit. So, stick with real automation, or use purpose-built GUI automation tools like `AutoIT,` `Selenium, etc.